# Login form using createForm with symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am newbie in `Symfony`. I just want to known if is it possible to create login form using `createForm` method. 
I already have a `LoginTYpe` class `implemanting buildForm` method which create an array whith all necessary fields for the form `(_username, _password, submit button)`.

In my controller, i use :

```
$form = $this->createForm(new LoginType(), $login, array('action' => $this->generateUrl('login_check')));
```

$`login` is just an instance of flat data class with members `(_username, _password)` getters and setters in Entity directory.

I render with :

```
return $this->render('LppdgProfessionalBookletBundle:Login:login.html.twig', array('error'=> $error, 'form' => $form->createView()));
```

Source of HTML form show :
`name="login[_username]"` for `"name"` field and `name="login[_password]` for"`password`" field.
Is there any way to avoid name field to be in array. 
Just more : when using manual form all works fine.

Thanks.

Laurent

Comment: What is the issue here exactly? Is that you don't want symfony to include the name attribute in the HTML? If so, out of curiosity, why is having the name attribute in the output undesirable for you?

Answer (score 0):

Set the names in your app/config/security.yml file:

```
        form_login:
            provider:            cerad_account_user_provider
            login_path:          cerad_account_login
            check_path:          cerad_account_login_check
            default_target_path: cerad_tourn_home

            username_parameter:  cerad_account_signin[username] # Adjust these three lines
            password_parameter:  cerad_account_signin[password]
            csrf_parameter:      cerad_account_signin[_token]
            csrf_provider:       form.csrf_provider
            intention:           authenticate
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine. I can customize my Entity fields as long as parameters are set correctly in the firewall.
I this example "login" (from the HTML source of form) is the return string of getName() method of my LoginType class.